# font size remains unchanged even though I have used \fontsize{8}{9.6}\selectfont

Tags: beamer, fontsize

The font size remains unchanged even though I have used 
`\fontsize{8}{9.6}\selectfont`

MWE:

```
\begin{frame}
    \begin{align}
    \fontsize{8}{9.6}\selectfont
    \frac{\partial^2 l}{\partial \gamma^2}=&\sum_{i=1}^{n} \delta_{E_i}\bigg[-\frac{e^{\beta_0+\beta_1 x_{i1}}}{\gamma}\bigg(t_i e^{\gamma t_i}\bigg(t_i-\frac{1}{\gamma}\bigg)-\frac{1}{\gamma^2}(1-e^{\gamma t_i})\bigg)
    \nonumber\\
    &+\frac{e^{\beta_0+\beta_1 x_{i1}}}{\gamma^2}\bigg(t_i e^{\gamma t_i}+\frac{1}{\gamma}(1-e^{\gamma t_i})\bigg)\bigg]\nonumber\\
    &+\delta_{R_i}\bigg[-\frac{e^{\beta_0+\beta_1 x_{i1}}}{\gamma}\bigg(t_{Ri} e^{\gamma t_{Ri}}\bigg(t_{Ri}-\frac{1}{\gamma}\bigg)-\frac{1}{\gamma^2}(1-e^{\gamma t_{Ri}})\bigg)
    \nonumber\\
    &+\frac{e^{\beta_0+\beta_1 x_{i1}}}{\gamma^2}\bigg(t_{Ri} e^{\gamma t_{Ri}}+\frac{1}{\gamma}(1-e^{\gamma t_{Ri}})\bigg)\bigg]\nonumber\\
    &+\delta_{I_i}\bigg[-\frac{e^{\beta_0+\beta_1 x_{i1}}}{\gamma}\bigg(t_{Ri}^2e^{\gamma t_{Ri}}-t_{Li}^2e^{\gamma t_{Li}}-\frac{1}{\gamma}(t_{Ri}e^{\gamma t_{Ri}}-\nonumber\\
    &t_{Li}e^{\gamma t_{Li}})-\frac{1}{\gamma^2}(e^{\gamma t_{Ri}}-e^{\gamma t_{Li}})\bigg)+\frac{e^{\beta_0+\beta_1 x_{i1}}}{\gamma^2}\bigg(t_{Ri} e^{\gamma t_{Ri}}-\nonumber\\
    &t_{Li} e^{\gamma t_{Li}}+\frac{1}{\gamma}(e^{\gamma t_{Ri}}-e^{\gamma t_{Li}})\bigg)\bigg]\\
    \nonumber
    \end{align}
\end{frame}
```

Comment: Math fonts are only influenced if `\selectfont` is before using a math formula. Use `\small` or whatever *before* `align`.

Comment: While you wait for an answer to this question, can you go back to your previous ones and look if the answers solve your problems and accept them, if they do?